# package.json not found in docker

Tags: docker, next.js

I have a problem.
Build project in docker and have error. That docker on            `npm install` not found ppackage.json

Dockerfile

```
FROM node

#copy source
COPY . /app

# Install deps
RUN cd /app && npm install

# Build
CMD npm run build

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

**BUT IN DOCKER PACKAGE.JSON EXIST**

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
2023-07-16T10:00:25.897789910Z npm ERR! syscall open
2023-07-16T10:00:25.898344831Z npm ERR! path /package.json
2023-07-16T10:00:25.899843841Z npm ERR! errno -2
2023-07-16T10:00:25.901767270Z npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/package.json'
2023-07-16T10:00:25.901968559Z npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
2023-07-16T10:00:25.902319000Z npm ERR! enoent 
2023-07-16T10:00:25.904753122Z 
2023-07-16T10:00:25.904888750Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-07-16T10_00_25_792Z-debug-0.log
2023-07-16T10:00:25.934642675Z
```

- Delete packagae-lock.json
- Rebuild container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to change the `cd` into `WORKDIR`

add `WORKDIR "/app"`

and you have 2 CMD commands, which will only execute the latter one.

Am not quite sure, but I guess your Dockerfile should look like this

```
FROM node

COPY . /app

WORKDIR "/app"

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build


CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```